# Extract number and operators from a String in Objective-C

Tags: regex, string, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I have this string `(2.5+1)*5`

I want to make a NSMutableArray containing each of the elements:
`[(, 2.5, +, 1, ), *, 5]`

This is the code I wrote:

```
+ (NSMutableArray*) convertToList: (NSString *) exp {
    NSRegularExpression * reg = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern: @"(\\d+\\.\\d+)|(\\d+)|([+-/*///^])|([/(/)])" options:0 error:nil];
    NSArray *matches = [ reg matchesInString: exp
                                 options: 0
                                   range:NSMakeRange(0, [exp length])];
    return [matches mutableCopy];
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    NSString * exp = @"(2+5)";
    NSMutableArray * array = [ExpressionTexting convertToList:exp];
    NSLog(@"%@", array);
}
```

I get this output:

```
(
"<NSExtendedRegularExpressionCheckingResult: 0x10010d2e0>{0, 1}{<NSRegularExpression: 0x10010abb0> (\\d+\\.\\d+)|(\\d+)|([+-/*///^])|([/(/)]) 0x0}",
"<NSExtendedRegularExpressionCheckingResult: 0x10010d3f0>{1, 1}{<NSRegularExpression: 0x10010abb0> (\\d+\\.\\d+)|(\\d+)|([+-/*///^])|([/(/)]) 0x0}",
"<NSExtendedRegularExpressionCheckingResult: 0x10010d470>{2, 1}{<NSRegularExpression: 0x10010abb0> (\\d+\\.\\d+)|(\\d+)|([+-/*///^])|([/(/)]) 0x0}",
"<NSExtendedRegularExpressionCheckingResult: 0x10010d4f0>{3, 1}{<NSRegularExpression: 0x10010abb0> (\\d+\\.\\d+)|(\\d+)|([+-/*///^])|([/(/)]) 0x0}",
"<NSExtendedRegularExpressionCheckingResult: 0x10010d570>{4, 1}{<NSRegularExpression: 0x10010abb0> (\\d+\\.\\d+)|(\\d+)|([+-/*///^])|([/(/)]) 0x0}"
)
```

In Java I got the answer:

```
public static ArrayList<String> convertToList(String exp){
    String regex = "(\\d+\\.\\d+)|(\\d+)|([+-/*///^])|([/(/)])";
    Matcher m3 = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(exp);
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(exp.length());
    while (m3.find()) {
        list.add(m3.group());
    }
    return list;
}
```

Which works, but I can't translate it in Objective-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, the error was due to the fact that I didn't really know how to handle the result, the NSArray returned is made of NSTextCheckingResult, which I have to use to extract the numbers and the operators.

```
+ (NSMutableArray*) convertToList: (NSString *) exp {
NSRegularExpression * reg = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern: @"(\\d+\\.\\d+)|(\\d+)|([+-/*///^])|([/(/)])" options:0 error:nil];
NSArray *matches = [ reg matchesInString: exp
                                 options: 0
                                   range:NSMakeRange(0, [exp length])];

NSMutableArray *mArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (NSTextCheckingResult *match in matches) {
    NSString* matchText = [exp substringWithRange:[match range]];
    [mArray addObject:matchText];
    //NSLog(@"%@", matchText);
}

return mArray;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use regex pattern

```
(\\d+\\.?\\d*|\\.\\d+|[^\\d.])
```

#### Java code:

```
String str = "(2.5+1)*5";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d+\\.?\\d*|\\.\\d+|[^\\d.])");
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
while (m.find()) {
    String match = m.group();
    System.out.println(match);
}
```

#### Output:

```
(
2.5
+
1
)
*
5
```

Check this code **[here](http://ideone.com/q07lD)**.

Comment: I get a warning: unknown escape sequence \. I think that the regex isn't the problem, it worked well in Java

Comment: @AR89 - Check the link of demo in my answer. Code should work without warnings.

Comment: @AR89 - The demo is for Java environment. I am not sure, but maybe Objective-c regex uses one escaping slash only, so try to use regex pattern `(\d+\.?\d*|\.\d+|[^\d.])` with Objective-c.

Comment: neither yours regex nor mine are wrong, they both works fine, looks at my answer. Thank you btw.

Comment: @AR89 - I am glad you found a solution :) Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need a math parser. 
check [DDMathParser](https://github.com/davedelong/DDMathParser)

Answer (score 0):

As was alluded to in another answer, [`DDMathParser`](https://github.com/davedelong/DDMathParser) can do this quite easily.  It looks like you don't care about the hierarchy of the actual terms, so you could get away with just using the resulting tokens.  That's easy:

```
    NSError *error = nil;
    DDMathStringTokenizer *tokenizer = [[DDMathStringTokenizer alloc] initWithString:@"(2.5+1)*5" error:&error];
    NSArray *tokens = [tokenizer tokens];
    tokens = [tokens valueForKey:@"token"];
    NSLog(@"%@", tokens);
```

The `-tokens` method on `DDMathStringTokenizer` returns an array of `DDMathStringToken` objects.  Those objects have an underlying `NSString` of the actual token (accessed via the `token` property), so you'll need the `valueForKey:` call on the array to turn it into an array of strings.  But if you do this, then you'll get this logged:

```
(
    "(",
    "2.5",
    "+",
    1,
    ")",
    "*",
    5
)
```